# How to fix nodemailer "object object" error in node.js website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun, nodemailer

I am creating a node.js website for a business and would like to be able to notify through email, everytime someone applies. I am using nodemailer and mailgun to send an email every time the job application form is submitted. The emails are being sent, however, it does not contain the key value pairs of the applicant object I've created. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is an image of the email I receive when submitting and application
[image]

Here is the nodemailer code I'm running

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailgun = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
const debug = require('debug')('app:mail');

const auth = {
    auth: {
       api_key: '**************',
       domain: '***************' 
    }
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailgun(auth));

function sendOrderEmail(applicant) {
  let html = '<ul>';

  Object.entries(applicant).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    html += `<li>${key}: ${value}</li>`;
  });

  html += '</ul>';

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '*************',
    to: '*********, *************',
    subject: '*****************',
    html
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      debug(`Error: ${err}`);
    } else {
      debug(`Info: ${info}`);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = sendOrderEmail;
```

Here is my post route where I create the applicant object

```
app.post('/employment', function(req, res){

    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var middleInitial = req.body.middleInitial;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var address = req.body.address;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var state = req.body.state;
    var zipCode = req.body.zipCode;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    var doYouRecieveText = req.body.doYouRecieveText;

    var newApplicant = {
        firstName: firstName,
        middleInitial: middleInitial,
        lastName: lastName,
        address: address,
        city: city,
        state: state,
        zipCode: zipCode,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        doYouRecieveText: doYouRecieveText
    };

    Applicant.create(newApplicant, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(newlyCreated);
            sendOrderEmail(newlyCreated);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to change your code to generate the HTML you want.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the help. Could you possibly give me an example? I am new to this. I would like to display all the values present in the newApplicant object

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `value` you are attempting to insert in your html is an Object but the html is expecting a value of type String.

Try stringifying your `value` before inserting it in your html.

```
html += `<li>${key}: ${ typeof value === 'string' ? value : JSON.stringify(value)}</li>`;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This ended up helping but was ultimately an error what I was passing through to the sendOrderEmail

Answer (score 0):

I was passing through the newlyCreated parameter to the sendOrderEmail function when I should have been passing through the newApplicant variable

```
Applicant.create(newApplicant, function(err, newlyCreated){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(newlyCreated);
        sendOrderEmail(newApplicant);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```